# C# finding totals from a file (has to be an easy answer)

Tags: c#, winforms

What I basically have is a file that formatted with Name|Value.

There is several different values through the whole file and for each value that matches my if statement I simply want to do total - value and then return the total to do the next calculation, so basically I have a file that is.

1|100
2|200
A|30
B|40

here is what i tried bit it didn't give me what i was looking for, it kept returing alpha and numb as the original value.

```
int alpha = 1000;
int numb= 500;
int numbtotal = 0;
string[] valu = File.ReadAllLines(subdirectory + "\\" + "values.txt");
foreach (string val in valu)
                {
                  string[] valusplit = val.Split('|');
if(valusplit[0].Equals("1"))
                  {
                      numbtotal = Convert.ToInt32(valusplit[1]);
                      numb = Math.Abs(numb - numbtotal); 
                  }
                  else if(valueplit[0].Equals("2"))
                  {
                      numbtotal = Convert.ToInt32(valusplit[1]);
                      numb = Math.Abs(numb - numbtotal);
                  }

                }
```

This basically kept doing 500 - the new valusplit value.  When I really wanted to do (500 - 100 = 400)  then (400 - 200 = 200) and get the value of 200.

Comment: So any line beginning with the number 1 or 2 you want to start with 500 and keep subtracting the file's value? You may try looking at `Int32.TryParse` as apposed to a `Convert.ToInt32`

Comment: Yeah basically, thanks i'll look.

Comment: Can you give us the *desired* output for this file?

Comment: I could, but it's really going to be injected into a SQL table, at the end of the day I want to read threw all my if statements and find the value of X, X being an original total - all of my if statements combined, but in my example i want the result of numb = 200 when it gets out of the foreach loop

Comment: @Mike: I tried your code, the final value of `numb` is 200, as expected. (Well, I didn't use file, constructed the array directly.)

Comment: i didn't lol, the values after breaking out of the foreach loop is still numb = 500;

Comment: @Mike: Look at the example: http://ideone.com/NOo3F

Comment: @Mike: maybe you are reading a wrong file? You should perhaps have a check what is in `valu` after `ReadAllLines`.

Comment: i'm not sure at this point, thanks, i think i might not have everything placed inside my void correctly, this will take some time to debug

Comment: There may be a scoping issue with the variables. Can you post more of the code?

Comment: @Mike - if numb is global variable, remove the local declaration inside the function.

Comment: Yes. We need to see more code to see how your variables are scoped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second if statement, you have misspelled `valusplit` as `valueplit`. If this code compiles as shown (IE `valueplit` is indeed a variable defined outside of this code), that would explain why you are getting the wrong result.

Comment: It's spelled that way throughout, I guess programmer short-hand.

Comment: Good catch, but he didn't misspell the first instance of "valusplit" where he is looking for the "1" value. Therefore, he would still have 400, not 500, for the value of "numb". I think we need to see more of the code.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your problem was "splitfilesys" instead of "valusplit" in the "elseif".

```
        int alpha = 1000;
        int numb = 500;
        int numbtotal = 0;

        //string[] values = File.ReadAllLines(subdirectory + "\\" + "values.txt");
        string[] values = new String[] { "1|100", "2|200", "A|30", "B|40" };
        foreach (string value in values)
        {
            string[] valueSplit = value.Split('|');
            switch (valueSplit[0])
            {
                case "1":
                    numb = Math.Abs(numb - Convert.ToInt32(valueSplit[1]));
                    break;

                case "2":
                    numb = Math.Abs(numb - Convert.ToInt32(valueSplit[1]));
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I didn't rename all the vars because I didn't want the solution to be so far away from the question that it didn't line up.

Comment: The post has been edited. The original code posted had a reference to "splitfilesys" instead of valueSplit in what would be the case "2" that you see in my answer.